# Keycloak Policy Enforcing

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

Application.properties:

```
    server.port=8180
    keycloak.realm = finaltest
    keycloak.auth-server-url = http://localhost:8080/auth
    keycloak.resource = ex
    keycloak.public-client=false
    keycloak.enabled=true
    keycloak.credentials.secret=secret
    keycloak.ssl-required = external
    keycloak.cors=true
    keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true

    keycloak.security-constraints[0].auth-roles[0]=master
    keycloak.security-constraints[0].security-collections[0].patterns[0]=/*

    keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.enforcement-mode=ENFORCING

    keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.lazy-load-paths=true
```

RESOURCES:
      I have two resources namely
         http://localhost:8180/flights.html
         http://localhost:8180/hotels.html
I have protected these using the policies in keycloak admin console.How do I enforce these policies in the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.enforcement-mode=ENFORCING this line will enforce policies.But you must have spring boot version 2.0 and above.

Comment: this is not working not worked on spring boot before. still giving error like : java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to obtain policy enforcer
 at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getPolicyEnforcer(KeycloakDeployment.ja